# Rails how to render a conditional partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now I have something like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "widgets/type1.html.erb", :locals => {:widget => @wall} %>
```

I have 50 different types

```
widgets/type1.html.erb
widgets/type2.html.erb
widgets/type3.html.erb
widgets/type4.html.erb
....
```

In the widget object, there is a widget.type which has the type2 etc... Is there a way I can make the partial dynamic to avoid all the if statements?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can tell rails to render :partial=>string, you can do string replacement inside that string. So, if @widget is the variable name:

```
<%= render :partial => "widgets/#{@widget.type}", :locals => {:widget => @wall} %>
```